# R task: Web Scraping With Rvest Giving Error

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I am a beginner in R. While going through the web scraping part using 'rvest package' , I came across an error. Request any one to help me on  that. I wrote a code that was suppose to scrape data from a website. However, I am not able to clean it up. The code was to scrape details of the price of mobile of a particular brand from Amazon's site. It is produced as under:-

```
samsung<- read_html("https://www.amazon.in/s?k=samsung+m12&sprefix=samsung+m%2Caps%2C253&ref=nb_sb_ss_ts-doa-p_1_9")
modelhtml<- html_nodes(samsung, ".a-size-medium.a-text-normal")
modeltext<- html_text(modelhtml)

pricehtml<- html_nodes(samsung,".a-price-whole")
pricetext<- html_text(pricehtml)

price1<- pricehtml
html_nodes(price1, ".a-price-whole")
html_text() 
readr::parse_character()
  
combined<- data_frame(samsungmod,'date and time' = Sys.time(), price)
```

however, I am getting errors in parse_number.

**html_nodes(price1, ".a-price-whole")
{xml_nodeset (0)}

> html_text()
> Error in xml_text(x, trim = trim) :
> argument "x" is missing, with no default**

Comment: `'https://www.amazon.in/s?k=samsung+m12&sprefix=samsung+m%2Caps%2C253&ref=nb_sb_ss_ts-doa-p_1_9' %>% read_html() %>% 
  html_nodes('.a-price-whole') %>% html_text()` worked in getting prices

Comment: Yes Nad ! it is working. However, I need to convert it into a nice table, which I am not being able to do.

Comment: Why are you using price1  with a CSS path in html_nodes()? Those results are would already be stored in the pricehtml object. If you do html_text(price1) does that achieve the results you are looking for?

Comment: The issue is some of the items don't have price tags thus uneven length in `model` and `price`

Comment: @EdgarZamora !, I corrected the code as you pointed out only to get the following errors:- 
> pricehtml<- html_nodes(samsung,".a-price-whole")
> pricetext<- html_text(pricehtml)
> price1<- pricehtml
> html_nodes( ".a-price-whole")
Error in UseMethod("xml_find_all") : 
  no applicable method for 'xml_find_all' applied to an object of class "character"
>

Comment: @Stefan Thank you very much. I got a solution. I was able to make a table. It's not a tidy one though :-      

< Samsung<- read_html("https://www.amazon.in/s?k=samsung+m12&sprefix=samsung+m%2Caps%2C253&ref=nb_sb_ss_ts-doa-p_1_9")
modelhtml<- html_nodes(samsung, ".a-size-medium.a-text-normal")
modeltext<- html_text(modelhtml)

pricehtml<- html_nodes(samsung,".a-price-whole")
pricetext<- html_text(pricehtml)

price1<- pricehtml
html_nodes(price1, ".a-price-whole")
X<- html_text(price1) 
readr::parse_character(c(X))

combined<- tibble(x= modeltext, y= (X))>

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all . I got a solution. I was able to make a table. It's not a tidy one though. Here is the script :-

```
 Samsung<- read_html("https://www.amazon.in/s?k=samsung+m12&sprefix=samsung+m%2Caps%2C253&ref=nb_sb_ss_ts-doa-p_1_9")
    modelhtml<- html_nodes(samsung, ".a-size-medium.a-text-normal")
    modeltext<- html_text(modelhtml)
    
    pricehtml<- html_nodes(samsung,".a-price-whole")
    pricetext<- html_text(pricehtml)
    
    price1<- pricehtml
    html_nodes(price1, ".a-price-whole")
    X<- html_text(price1) 
    readr::parse_character(c(X)


combined<- tibble(x= modeltext, y= (X))
```

Kindly comment.